# nginx showing blank page everytime I restart - behind AWS load balancer

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, load-balancing

nginx keeps showing a blank page every time I run a service nginx reload and then finally starts displaying my content after 5 to 10 minutes of running a nginx reload. I don't know why this keeps on happening I'm using a basic nginx config with php enabled. I have a feeling it could do with AWS ELB or possibly AWS route 53, but I'm not sure. At this point it's becoming a pain as I can't do any advanced configuration before I get this resolved; I have to wait 10 minutes just to find out if my configuration is working as expected. I would also like to mention that I have php7.0-fpm installed and I'm using an AWS EC2 Ubuntu server.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Check your logs.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks! if you're referring to my nginx access and error logs I already checked them and nothing displays during this 5 to 10 minute window. I tried this a number of times with no success. Do you have any Idea what the issue could be?

Comment: How did you configure the health checks on the balancer?  The most likely explanation is that the balancer is returning the blank page along with a `503` error because your instance is considered unhealthy.  What do the balancer metrics show?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yup that's correct I'm getting a 503 error. My balancer is showing that it is OutOfService. This happens every time I make a change to the nginx config and restart it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this problem. The whole reason I was getting a blank white page (503 Error)  was because every time I restarted nginx the load balancer was set to do 10 health checks before it was considered healthy. I set the ELB healthy threshold down from 10 to 2 and set the interval for checks every 5 seconds and now my content loads immediately a maximum of 10 seconds.

BTW this will also fix a 503 error with Apache assuming you are using a balancer. I'm sure this will save someone a big headache.